# What is the easiest Way to convert VCalender to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm reading an VCalender ics file in my app and like to convert DTSTART to a DateTime Object.

the Datestring looks like this:

```
DTSTART:20150215T124500Z
```

easiest way to convert this string.

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` with the customized format. Search for DateTime Format C#

Comment: `DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(DTSTART, "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
var result = DateTime.ParseExact("20150215T124500Z", "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var str = "20150215T124500Z";
string format = "yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
   //good date
}
```